# Form Validation Hack character count

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am writing this code to count the characters inside the form. Though it works in the sense it's not actually counting I think. I keep getting the alert that it hasn't reached it's minimum count

```
$(function(){
  var minLength = 10;
  var form = $('form[action*="post"]');
form.submit(function (e) {
  var mini = $('#text_editor_textarea');
       if (mini.text().length < minLength) {
    alert ('You need to enter at least' +minLength + ' characters');
  e.preventDefault();
   }
   else if (mini.text().length > minLength) {
}
 });
});
```

Now my else if should pass I thought since really it has no restrictions within the statement whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, `mini` is the result of `.val`, which is a string. what you need, is to use `mini.length`

update: I meant

```
var mini = $(element).val().length;
// .val() gives the text, .length gives the string's length
```

Comment: still getting error, it will not pass at all. Also I thought to get the inner text of a textarea or input we had to use .val()

Comment: yes. you have to use `.val`, but that gives you the text, then you need the length.